# Show alert popup 5 mins before a specific time

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-4, nosql

Currently i am developing and an Schedule appointment module and in that there is an feature to show an alert to the user 5 mins before appointment time , for example the appointment is scheduled @5pm today then the user should be notified with the alert or popup @4:55 pm that the meeting is due in 5 mins.

I am using PHP and javascript for this project and True Vault to save the data in database which is in No - Sql ,

So just needed to know what is the best way to achieve this without using the cronjobs or features similar to that.

Thanks for any kind of help...

Comment: You could set up polling. So your application makes an ajax request every.. let's say 10 seconds to check if there are any alerts to show. If yes the information gets returned by the server and the client shows the popup.

Comment: you can't use cron - thats' a server-side thing. if this in a client-side browser-based system, then you'd need to just set a timeout. stuff the appointment time into a variable, then start a `setTimeout` based on how many seconds there are until 5 minutes before that time. the timeout pops up the alert.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this if you are using a client-side based system:

```
var now = new Date();
var millisTill10 = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 10, 0, 0, 0) -now;

if (millisTill10 < 0) 
{
     millisTill10 += 86400000; // 10AM in this case
}

setTimeout(function(){alert("It is time!")}, millisTill10);
```